# Google Calender API in PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to implement google calender api v3 in code ignitor.
Someone please explain how I can achieve this?
Is it easy for PHP and google api beginner?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, It's very easy. https://github.com/seanmcgary/Codeigniter-Gcal